# TextView click listener not being called

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a TextView on an android app clickable, but the listener isn't being called.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_oggi"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_oggi_title_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:text="Oggi"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="21dp"
        android:paddingTop="80dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:clickable="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

That is the fragment, and I'm trying to make "fragment_oggi_title_textview" clickable.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_oggi, container, false);

    view.post(() -> {
        TextView textView = (TextView) MainActivity.getInstance().findViewById(R.id.fragment_oggi_title_textview);

        textView.setClickable(true);
        textView.setFocusable(true);

        formattedDate = format.format(calendar.getTime());
        textView.setText(String.format("Oggi (%s)", formattedDate));

        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateListener = (view1, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth) -> {
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.detach(this);
            fragmentTransaction.attach(this);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            System.out.println("CLICK1!");
        };

        textView.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) v -> {
            new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.getInstance(), dateListener, calendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            System.out.println("CLICK!");
        });
    });

    return view;
}
```

That is my Fragment class. I'm setting the TextView clickable and focusable. Sadly, when I click on the TextView from an emulator and from an actual phone, the listener isn't called. The only time when it's called is when I select it with my keyboard and press it with the enter key. Does anyone have an idea of what I could be doing wrong?

Edit: The TextVuew was being covered by the listview, which is why I couldn't click it.

Comment: where is your text view defined?  fragment_oggi.xml file that you are inflating for a fragment or in the activity.

Comment: TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_oggi_title_textview);

Comment: I create it in the MainActivity class. https://pastebin.com/1q1LbrgJ

Comment: Could you explain a bit better? Sorry for not understanding, but I'm new to the android framework.

Comment: @SearchForMe I got 2 questions for you: 1. Why did you use `view.post()` cause there is a better way to implement  that and I can show you. 2. Why do you have to call `MainActivity.getInstance().findViewById()`? Is the `TextView` located only in the `MainActivity`'s layout?

Comment: No, but I wouldn't know how else to get it @Kidus

Comment: `MainActivity.getInstance()` is _very_ suspicious looking. What value does `getInstance()` return? Instead you should try `(MainActivity) getActivity()`.

Comment: getInstance simply returns itself. I wasn't aware of other methods of getting the Activity, so I resorted to that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the TextView is in the **Activity** You can create a getter in your Activity to get your TextView like this :

```
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            /*
            rest of your code
             */
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }

    public TextView getTextView() {
        return textView;
    }
}
```

and in your Fragment inside onCreateView() :

```
TextView textView = ((YourActivity)requireActivity()).getTextView();
```

And if your TextView is in The **Fragment** just use

```
TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_oggi_title_textview);
```

**UPDATE**

The reason why your TextView is not receiving click events is because it is covered  by the ListView in your layout you need to check your Layout

Comment: That is practically the same as what I'm doing right now. Since the code I'm using is executed in the onCreateView method, I guess the TextView isn't added yet as a component, hence why it's null. This is of course only an assumption

Comment: your text is in the activity or in a Fragment ?

Comment: In a fragment. Do you need me to upload the code somewhere?

Comment: That did solve the NPE, but sadly the listener still isn't called.

Comment: the reason why your Textview is not clickable because is hidden by the listView Check your layout organization

Comment: please add this         `android:layout_below="@id/fragment_oggi_title_textview"`
 in your listView in the layout and check if your lisner is called and let me know

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved the issue.

Comment: ok fine please if you want to mark this answer as helpful to help other perssone

Answer (score 0):

Just keep it simple and do it like this :

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_oggi, container, false);

    TextView textView =findViewById(R.id.fragment_oggi_title_textview);

        formattedDate = format.format(calendar.getTime());
        textView.setText(String.format("Oggi (%s)", formattedDate));

        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateListener = (view1, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth) -> {
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.detach(this);
            fragmentTransaction.attach(this);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            System.out.println("CLICK1!");
        };

        textView.setOnClickListener( v -> {
            new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.getInstance(), dateListener, calendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            System.out.println("CLICK!");
        });

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Sadly that causes an exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setClickable(boolean)' on a null object reference

Comment: Yeah it should since your textview is actually in the host activity and not in the fragment , I updated it .

Comment: No, the TextView is in the Fragment. How would I get it? Would I have to create it programmatically rather than in the Fragment class?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that you don't need the `view.post()` because `Fragment` has it's own method `OnViewCreated` which returns the `View` after the `View` is created. And Second, you can use the returned `view` to find your `TextView`. So reformat the code in your `fragment` like this:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_oggi, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

            TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_oggi_title_textview);

            formattedDate = format.format(calendar.getTime());
            textView.setText(String.format("Oggi (%s)", formattedDate));

            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateListener = (view1, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth) -> {
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.detach(this);
            fragmentTransaction.attach(this);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            System.out.println("CLICK1!");
        };

        textView.setOnClickListener( v -> {
            new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.getInstance(), dateListener, calendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            System.out.println("CLICK!");
        });
}
```